# Chain methods in Python like JavaScript?

Tags: python

Hello I am mainly a JavaScript developer learning some Python
and I was doing the isPalindrome algorithm

I wrote this in JS

```
function isPalindrome(string) {
 const reverseStr = string.split('').reverse().join('');
  return string === reverseStr;
}

console.log(isPalindrome('abcdcba'))
```

But I had a hard time replicating this logic in python

Here is what i have so far

```
def isPalindrome(string):
 reverseStr = list(string)
 reverseStr.reverse()
 print(reverseStr)
 # return string == reverseStr
```

print(isPalindrome('abcdcba'))

How can I chain methods in Python like JavaScript?
Thanks

Comment: this question should be asked in python community

Comment: Python is not JS so if you want to chain, you'll need to write your own string subclass that supports self method calls rather than loose global functions. But I suggest not doing that because it's un-Pythonic and surprising. Best to use languages as idiomatically as possible. Some Python libraries use a lot of chaining, like Pandas, but the standard library isn't written like this by design. Also, be sure to indent/format code properly when posting (it takes some practice, but you can [edit] your post). Thanks.

Comment: BTW, the creator of Python doesn't like method chaining, but I can't find the post or message where he explains why offhand...

Comment: In this specific case you can't chain the functions, because `.reverse()` is an in-place operation; it doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reverse the list of chars you need to rejoin using `join` method of strings in Python, so

```
def isPalindrome(string):
    reverseStr = list(string)
    reverseStr.reverse()
    return string == ''.join(reverseStr)
```

It works, but the easier way to check for palindromes as highlighted by [porrrwal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70050476/3558077) is `string == string[::-1]`

Comment: what does the string[::-1] mean?

Comment: That means string slice, by example if s='123456', s[::2] = '135'(slice of two), if the given number is negative, then the slice is in reverse order, so s[::-2]= '642'

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple to do in python. Try this:

```
string == string[::-1]
```

So for your function you can just use:

```
def isPalindrome(string):
    return string == string[::-1]
```